# How to check and get data which is in_array with while loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two tables, and I want to get the result which only match in the array, here is the database:
table `pinned`, it store the apply place of articles

```sql
| id | article_id | pinned_sort | apply |
| 1 | 121 | 1 | a:1:{i:0;i:1;} |
| 2 | 148 | 1 | a:3:{i:0;i:2;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;} |
| 3 | 210 | 1 | a:3:{i:0;i:3;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;} |
```

table `article`, it store the articles

```sql
| aid | title |
| 121 | Test 1 |
| 148 | Test 2 |
| 210 | Test 3 |
```

And here is my function

```php
<?php
    function getArticlePinned($connectdb, $board_id = '')
    {
        $board_id = (int) $board_id;
        if (!empty($board_id)) {
            $read['query'] = 'SELECT 
            article.aid,
            article.title,
            pinned.apply 
            FROM pinned 
            INNER JOIN article ON article.aid = pinned.article_id 
            ORDER BY pinned_sort ASC';
            //Get result
            $read['stmt'] = $connectdb->stmt_init();
            $read['stmt']->prepare($read['query']);
            $read['stmt']->execute();
            $read['result'] = $read['stmt']->get_result();
            if ($read['result']->num_rows != 0) {
                while ($read['row'] = $read['result']->fetch_assoc()) {
                    //Get array from unserialize
                    $pinnedArray = unserialize($read['row']['apply']);
                    if (is_array($pinnedArray)) {
                        //Check if the board id is in array
                        if (in_array($board_id, $pinnedArray) === true) {
                            $result[] = $read['row'];
                        } else {
                            $result = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $result = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $result = false;
            }
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

But very strange is that only when `$board_id` is `1`,it can get result...

Comment: What ?! but the array is generate by `serialize` function...

Comment: @04FS test for this ```$array = array(1,2,3); echo serialize($array);```

Comment: And it return this `a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should initialise $result = false by default and let below code runs as per it.

```
function getArticlePinned($connectdb, $board_id = '')
{
    $board_id = (int) $board_id;
    $result   = false;
    if (!empty($board_id)) {
        $read['query'] = 'SELECT
            article.aid,
            article.title,
            pinned.apply
            FROM pinned
            INNER JOIN article ON article.aid = pinned.article_id
            ORDER BY pinned_sort ASC';
        //Get result
        $read['stmt'] = $connectdb->stmt_init();
        $read['stmt']->prepare($read['query']);
        $read['stmt']->execute();
        $read['result'] = $read['stmt']->get_result();
        if ($read['result']->num_rows != 0) {
            while ($read['row'] = $read['result']->fetch_assoc()) {
                //Get array from unserialize
                $pinnedArray = unserialize($read['row']['apply']);
                //Check if the board id is in array
                if (is_array($pinnedArray) && in_array($board_id, $pinnedArray)) {
                    $result[] = $read['row'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/e44aG).

Comment: Because in while loop you were checking if board_id exists or not, if not exists then you were resetting/ removing the result array, if match then it was adding the data in result, so subsequently, you were adding and removing data from $result array. I hope I am clear.

Comment: Oh I got it, you means that I just set `$result` to true and reset it to false when `$board_id` isn't in array, thanks a lot !!!!!

Comment: Exactly you got me :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god ! I fixed it !! I just remove `$result = false;` when `in_array` return false, here is the code:

```php
if (in_array($board_id, $pinnedArray) === true) {
    $result[] = $read['row'];
}
```

Instead of

```php
if (in_array($board_id, $pinnedArray)) {
    $result[] = $read['row'];
} else {
    $result = false;
}
```

Still don't know why but it works...

Comment: And can you compare it with my solution, have I gave something different that you just posted?

Comment: @DrakulaPredator oh I'm sorry, I haven't watch your code totally, I thought that you only add `$result = false;` on the beginning of the script ...